# Create i18n homepage in Symfony 2.2?

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization, routes, translation

I implemented small icons to switch between languages and get back to the same page, but I get stuck with the new Symfony2.2 `_locale` behaviour.

```
<a class="lang" href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'fr'})) }}">
    <img src="{{ asset('bundles/fuzlayout/images2/locale_fr.png') }}" title="Français" alt="Français" />
</a>
 &nbsp;
<a class="lang" href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'})) }}">
    <img src="{{ asset('bundles/fuzlayout/images2/locale_en.png') }}" title="English" alt="English" />
</a>
```

This displays :

[image]

If I click on a locale everywhere on my website, this is ok because all routes takes the famous `_locale` argument, for example, if I am in the following page :

```
fuz_home_test:
    pattern:  /{_locale}/test
    defaults: { _controller: FuzHomeBundle:Default:test }
    requirements:
      _locale: fr|en
```

The URL generated by the following route will be `/fr/test` or `/en/test`.

But, my homepage can't have the `_locale` parameter :

```
fuz_home:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: FuzHomeBundle:Default:index }
```

If I put a default argument such as :

```
fuz_home:
    pattern:  /{_locale}
    defaults: { _controller: FuzHomeBundle:Default:index, _locale: %locale% }
    requirements:
      _locale: fr|en
```

By default, Symfony will use the fallback locale instead of the user original's one.

So my question is : how to create a multi-language homepage ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending my whole eveening on the problem, I finally got a solution.

You need to bind `/` to a controller that will redirect user to the right translated homepage according to his locale.

In your routing :

```
fuz_index:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: FuzHomeBundle:Default:index }

fuz_home:
    pattern:  /{_locale}
    defaults: { _controller: FuzHomeBundle:Default:home }
    requirements:
      _locale: fr|en
```

In your controller :

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $router = $this->get('router');
    $locale = $this->getRequest()->getLocale(); // here is the magic!
    $url = $router->generate('fuz_home', array('_locale' => $locale));
    return new RedirectResponse($url);
}

public function homeAction()
{
    return $this->render('FuzHomeBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
}
```

## Edit

I finally installed [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle) that manages i18n transparently using the standard routing. Far, far easier than the Symfony2's built-in way to do it, especially on special views (404 / errors fallbacks, log-in request page...).